# Manually-modified ADB backup file cannot be restored on a different device

Tags: adb, root-access, backup, restore

While there are tons of posts about ADB, I think we can all agree it is an elusive beast.  Therefore asking if anyone can shed some light on the following:

The objective is to backup data from an app on **device #1**, change some database data in the app's database file stored in `root/data/data/com.AppName.../apps/db`, repackage the changes into an .ab and restore it to **device #2** which will have the same App installed.

I have managed to create a **.ab via adb backup** (without .apk), have manipulated the db data after unpacking it from the .ab and have packed everything back into a .ab ready for restore to a new target device.

However, the restore does not yield any change on the new target device where the app has been pre-installed. [This post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155957/cannot-restore-an-adb-backup-due-to-a-tarball-with-a-broken-header/247061#247061) seems to suggest that the app has to be installed via adb in order to get the data loaded.... but I'm not sure I'm understanding that.

I do have a copy of the .apk for the app which I could point to the mentioned restore script, but just not sure if that's the thing to do.

One more note is that **I am working with unrooted devices**. While I can see how adb backup could easily have read permission to app data, I never understood whether adb restore has permission by default to write app data to its destination under /root/data/data.

Sorry for the long post but just trying to be clear.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Are the source and the target device using the same Android version? It seems like Google has deactivated adb backup and restore on Android 12 if the app's targetSdkVersion exceeds a certain value. Not sure about Android 11.

Comment: Hi, I tried to clarify the title because the original revision was unclear about the real issue. If it doesn't seem to be what you're asking, consider [edit]ing and clarifying it more. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Target device is running Android 10.

Comment: Just to clarify a little further, I found it wasn't necessary to take the data from device #1.  I actually only needed to take a backup from device #2, modify the database data mentioned and now wanting to **_restore the data back to device #2_**.  

Therefore disregard any mention of device #1.  The problem is simply not being able to get the repackaged .ab to **restore to device #2 running Android 10**.

Also, only had luck using **ADB 1.0.31** to perform the **backup**.   Tried several other versions including current from platform-tools.

Comment: Instead of using `adb restore` I would copy the .ab file to the phone and use the command `bu` inside `adb shell`. `adb backup` is just a wrapper for this bu binary, but executing it directly on the phone has the advantage that you see all potential error and warning messages. In parallel I recommend to have an `adb logcat` running to see if there are error message in logcat why the restore does not work.

Comment: @Robert.
I did previously try placing the .ab on the /sdcard part of internal storage and tried using the 'bu restore' command, but sadly that does not work either.

Interestingly, the syntax of 'bu' is a bit mysterious but is the only thing I could use to successfully make a backup with syntax like: 'bu 1 backup -apk app.package.name > /sdcard/backup.ab' (on an older device). This syntax did not work on new device. {all very confusing}.

Anyhow, will try your advice of watching 'logcat' in parallel in a separate 'adb' window.

Comment: I already had the case that the `bu` binary was simply malfunctioning on a device with stock ROM. In my case it just failed to start but it is also possible that it starts but then fails to do something. As `adb backup` is deprecated and no longer mentioned in adb help it would be possible that it is also not part of the Android compatibility test suite and thus an manufacturer will not recognize that it does not work at all.

Comment: @Robert, do you know for sure as of what Android version `adb` was deprecated?

Comment: Adb backup deprecation was at least three years ago, but I don't remember when exactly or on which version it happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137013/discussion-between-mmediaman-and-robert).